# How do I create a new type-safe primitive type, based on Int?

Tags: swift, types, functional-programming

Problem context: I'm learning functional domain modeling and Swift at the same time. The examples I am working from are in F#. One such example is of declaring single case unions:

```
//F# code
type CustomerId = CustomerId of int
type OrderId = OrderId of int

let customerId = CustomerId 42
let orderId = OrderId 42

printfn "%b" (orderId = customerId) //produces a compile error
```

So it appears to be super-easy, in F#, to declare type-safe primitives that are both essentially `Ints`.
In Swift `typealias` does not do the same thing:

```
typealias CustomerId = Int
typealias OrderId = Int

let customerId: CustomerId = 42
let orderId: OrderId = 42

customerId == orderId // true!
```

Now, I understand that all primitive types in Swift are essentially `struct`s, but I'm nowhere near sophisticated enough to understand the Swift code base to figure out how `Int` was created.
Does anyone know of a simple type-safe Swift equivalent to the F# declaration?

Comment: Good article about this topic: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/type-safe-identifiers-in-swift/

Comment: Thank you dan, that's really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

`typealias` is literally just an alias. It does not create a type. It just makes it easier to type the thing being aliased.

The way to do what you're trying to do is:

```
struct CustomerID {
    let value: Int
}

struct OrderID {
    let value: Int
}
```

If you want a "bare" initializer (`CustomerID(4)` rather than `CustomerID(value: 4)`), you could add that:

```
struct CustomerID {
    let value: Int
    init(_ value: Int) { self.value = value }
}
```

Since you'd probably do that a lot, you can extract it into a protocol

```
protocol Identifier {
    typealias IDType
    init(value: IDType)
}

extension Identifier {
    init(_ value: Int) { self.init(value: value) }
}

extension CustomerID: Identifier {}
```

And of course you could add similar extensions using `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` if you wanted syntax like `= 42`.

The specific syntax you're discussing in F# is often referred to in the Swift world by its Haskell name, newtype. Swift doesn't have a feature as easy to use as newtype, and [it's been discussed several times](https://forums.swift.org/t/newtype-without-automatic-protocol-forwarding/16110/7). There are several corner cases in Swift where it's a bit complicated to decide how you would automatically conform to protocols (particularly protocols that require Self). But it may be implemented some day.

You can see a much more in-depth discussion of this a [2019 AltConf talk on the subject](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXwJg0QTlZE).

Comment: Thank you Rob, that's a great answer! The YouTube video was awesome, if a little over my head - the 20min mark really tackled this issue head-on, though. It's making me really think hard about all the consequences and implications, which is good.

Comment: Hi Rob, do you know of a fairly compact write up of how to get a new `Int` like type to behave more like an `Int`? Eg, support numeric operators and such, implement comparable, hashable, strideable, and so on? It feels like it is probably a chunk of work and I'm not completely sure what else I'd want it to have! But perhaps it's not as much as I think and is pretty easily achieved? My use case is I want a type to represent `Semitones`. I'd want it to do anything `Int` does, but not be an `Int`… currently I just `typealias Semitones = Int` though! Thanks.

Comment: There's no automatic way to pass-through methods to the wrapped type. A few things are automatic (Hashable, Codable), but most you just write the things you need. That said, Semitones is a great example where you wouldn't want to get everything from Int. What does it mean to multiply or divide Semitones? What would a bit-wise AND of two Semitones represent? While it's slightly tedious to implement the needed methods, I expect there really aren't that many of them. For an example, see https://github.com/rnapier/OScope/blob/master/SignalKit/SignalKit/Time.swift

Comment: I'm not exactly certain what you're representing by a Semitones. Is it a frequency, an interval, or an offset within a scale? What it means will heavily define what operations make sense. For example, a natural way to think of this would be that Semitone is the Stride of Note, not that Semitone is itself Strideable. A classic mistake in using Int for these things is that many distinct concepts accidentally get merged into a single type.

Comment: Right – yes! In this case, `Semitones` is an interval between absolute notes. I am currently using `Int` for it. The type should support addition and subtraction and be `Strideable`. I'm going to change it to use [point-free's "Tagged" library](https://github.com/pointfreeco/swift-tagged), which will make it a distinct type. It also gives a reasonable guide to the interfaces I'd want to implement if I did write it as a distinct type myself.

Comment: You queried if these `Semitones` should be `Strideable`. I think in my case it probably makes sense for it to conform as it makes sense to be able to iterate through a range of `Semitones` (for frets positions of an instrument as a potential example).